# HTML img tag src with symlinked path not work

Tags: html, express

is there a way to show symlinked img correctly via src attribute?

The server is running by [express](http://expressjs.com/), and the symlinked image is serving by [static file](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

- use symlink file  `<img src="http://server:3000/public/1-symlinked.jpg" />`, it doesn't work.
- use normal file `<img src="http://server:3000/public/1.jpg" />`, it  works.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to save the image in your HTML Folder than you have to open the folder in your vs code than you can use tis tag it will work
`<img scr="your  image name ">` eg : `<img scr= " image.png">`

Comment: `img scr` you sure about that spelling?